# Rechart Scatter tooltip to show additional prop

Tags: recharts

I'm using a Scatter chart from Rechart

The data is displaying fine  but I want to tooltip to display an additional pop (the name of the item), just like it does on a Barchart. I've found that I could completely customize the tooltip but I wonder if there is an easier way ? like a prop that i don't know how to use. [the doc](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip) isn't very explicit on how to use some of the props

here's the code. You can see that I've tried datakey and label, but without success

```
<ScatterChart
          width={400}
          height={400}
          margin={{
            top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20,
          }}
        >
          <CartesianGrid />
          <XAxis type="number" dataKey="sizeMB" name="Size" unit=" MB" />
          <YAxis type="number" dataKey="directReferenceCount" name="# of References" unit=" References" />
          <Tooltip cursor={{ strokeDasharray: '3 3' }} dataKey={'fullName'} label={'fullName'} />
          <Scatter name="Line Item" data={this.props.data} fill="#8884d8">

          </Scatter>
        </ScatterChart>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find a solution other than using the full custom tooltip. here's the code:

```
  const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
  if (active) {
    return (
      <div className="custom-tooltip">
        <p className="intro">{payload[0].payload.fullName}</p>
        <p className="desc">size: {payload[0].payload.sizeMB}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
};
```

And I had some trouble finding the same css as the original tooltip but here it is:

```
.custom-tooltip{
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    padding: 10px;
}

.intro {
  border-top: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
}

.desc {
  margin: 0;
  color: rgb(3, 62, 146)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the custom tooltip slightly to include a check for payload aswell

```
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
  if (active && payload) {
    return (
      <div className="custom-tooltip">
        <p className="intro">{payload[0].payload.fullName}</p>
        <p className="desc">size: {payload[0].payload.sizeMB}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
};
```